# AppleScript to Rename File Names

Tags: applescript

Can anybody help me with the following issue.   I'd like an AppleScript that will rename files like these by removing the leading numbers and underscore.

So file names like these:

```
5111632_The Secret_ Dare to Dream.mp4
5099299_Invasion of the Body Snatchers 1.mp4
5099287_Basic Instinct.mp4
5099283_Before I Go to Sleep.mp4
```

would turn into:

```
The Secret_ Dare to Dream.mp4
Invasion of the Body Snatchers 1.mp4
Basic Instinct.mp4
Before I Go to Sleep.mp4
```

I'm going to run it in one folder using Hazel.

Comment: These sound like movie files.  Are you aware there is a very, very widespread––almost standardised––method of naming movie files, and lots of software to help do this automatically. The benefits of following the naming convention are saving yourself a headache of deciding on your own convention and changing it over and over again; organised filesystem aided by software that does the work for you; and being able to find movies online far easier because they all follow the same naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

The Applescript-native way to rename files is:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFile to (choose file)
    set name of theFile to "Yay"
end tell
```

If you wanted to rename every file in a folder, I'd put the files into a list and use a `Repeat` block on each one:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFolder to (choose folder)
    set folderContents to every item of theFolder
    repeat with theFile in folderContents
        set name of theFile to "Yay"
    end repeat
end tell
```

(This code won't actually run as-is because you can't have two files named "Yay", but the first does get renamed, and you get the idea.)

This is closer to what you want to do, but we're not quite there—you want to get the current file's name, make some changes to it, and save the new name.

There's a subroutine I found years ago somewhere (I can't seem to find the source now) which will get everything to the right of a certain character, such as an underscore. This makes it easy to do exactly what you want. The full, final code is:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFolder to (choose folder)
    set folderContents to every item of theFolder
    repeat with theFile in folderContents
        set oldName to name of theFile
        set newName to my rightString(oldName, "_")
        set name of theFile to newName
    end repeat
end tell

on rightString(str, del)
    local str, del, oldTIDs
    set oldTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    try
        set str to str as string
        if str does not contain del then return str
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to del
        set str to str's text items 2 thru -1 as string
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTIDs
        return str
    on error eMsg number eNum
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTIDs
        error "Can't rightString: " & eMsg number eNum
    end try
end rightString
```

Comment: Multiple files in the same folder sharing the same name. When I ran the script, it didn't overwrite the existing file, it just error'd out. That was okay since it was an in-between script for explanation, but I wanted to explain that the code wouldn't fully run!

Comment: @CJK Ah, missed that! I didn’t want to turn that on because if someone runs it in a folder with real data, the data would be destroyed! Better to let it error. The purpose of that code block was to get the point across; the last set of code is the real thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know anything about Hazel. However, this following AppleScript code will remove everything to the left of and including the 1st “_” from the names of the selected files in Finder and rename the selected files accordingly.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to (get selection)
    repeat with i from 1 to count of theFiles
        set thisFile to item i of theFiles
        set thisName to name of thisFile
        set theOffset to my (offset of "_" in thisName)
        set newName to text (theOffset + 1) ¬
            thru -1 of thisName
        set name of thisFile to newName
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: You shouldn't nest a `tell current application` block inside a `tell application "Finder"` block. That said, it's pretty zany that you've explicitly used `tell current application`.  I think you're trying to use the **`offset`** command without having to exit a Finder block: I think you're looking for either the word ***`my`*** or **`continue`**, i.e. `set theOffset to my (offset of ..)` or `set theOffset to continue offset of ...` (the use of `continue` being the more preferable).

Comment: Just noticed the line `set newName to characters (theOffset + 1) thru -1 of thisName as string`.  As there's no requirement to split the string into characters only to concatenate them again––which makes them subject to `text item delimiters`, which you haven't set prior to this operation––it's much more advisable to do `set newName to text (theOffset + 1) thru -1 of thisName`. This performs a direct substring grab, without the inbetween splitting and joining, which makes it faster, but importantly avoids any trouble with TIDs that you can't be sure of their value unless you explicitly set it.

Comment: @CJK  I feel like I just got my knuckles smacked with a ruler by my teacher LOL.  On a more serious note, thank you for your constructive criticism’s. I must admit, I continue to learn from you.

Comment: Sorry for how it sounds. It's a combination of word limit, British tone, my tendency to forget social etiquette, and how much time I put into rewriting what I type versus posting the first thing that comes out. Perhaps there is a teacher element, in that I **know** what you _can_ do, but sometimes see you get lazy or have some weird justification, both being quite schoolboy-like and frustrating. But I know I wouldn't make a very good school teacher for all of these reasons bar word limit. **Unrelated footnote:** your scripts now are way better than a few years ago.